# multiple times character entry using bufferedreader in java

Tags: bufferedreader

I am trying to enter a letter and a number. 1st input going fine but 2nd input its not taking rather going to the end of line stating not a digit. Please help.

```
public class charString {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader read=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(read);     
    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    char p=(char)(in.read());
    if(Character.isLetter(p))
        System.out.println(p+" is a letter");
    else
        System.out.println(p+" is not a letter");                  
    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    char p1=(char)(in.read());
    if(Character.isDigit(p))
        System.out.println(p1+" is a digit");
    else
        System.out.println(p1+" is not a digit");
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
   InputStreamReader read=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(read);     
   System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
   String character = in.next();
   char p = character.charAt(0);  

   characterChecker(p); 
 }

 private void characterChecker(Char p) {

   if(Character.isLetter(p)) {
      System.out.println(p+" is a letter");
   } else if (Character.isDigit(p)) {
      System.out.println(p1+" is a digit");
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**  You can also check out

```
Character.isLetterOrDigit(charAt(p))
```

hope this helps ..